# AJAX Error response

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

I am making an ajax call using JQuery $.ajax function.  I always want to make the same request, however in some states I want to return a "error condition" in which I simply want to alert to the user that an error occurred. I am using Struts 2 as my framework.  If I throw an error while generating the jsp page, would that trigger the JQuery error function even though the actual request would have been successful?  Here is my ajax request.  Thanks!

```
$(".autoFlowForm").submit(function() {
    var query = "resetFlow.action?" + $( this ).serialize() + "&ajax=true";
    var recoverBtn = $(this).children($(".btn"));
    recoverBtn.addClass("btn-warning");
    recoverBtn.addClass("disabled");
    recoverBtn.val("In Progress");
     $.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         url : query,
         success : function(result) {
             recoverBtn.removeClass("btn-warning");
             recoverBtn.removeClass("disabled");
             recoverBtn.val("Recover");
         },
         error : function() {
             alert("The flow is already being processed by " +
                    "another user, please try again in a few minutes.");
             recoverBtn.removeClass("btn-warning");
             recoverBtn.removeClass("disabled");
             recoverBtn.val("Recover");
         }
     });
     return false;
});
```

Comment: That sounds like something you could very easily test.  Without seeing server-side code it's hard to be specific, but if the request returns an HTTP error code then it would trigger the `error` AJAX handler.  There are many HTTP codes to choose from, you can pick the one that fits your condition best.  `500` tends to be something of a catch-all.

Comment: So I can trigger a 500 HTTP response from my Struts logic?  How would I do that?

Comment: That I don't know, I've never used JSP.  But the point is that any HTTP error condition is going to trigger the `error` handler in your AJAX function.

Comment: That should be good enough to get me started.  Thanks!

Comment: You can either return JSON data that embeds error information, or set the HTTP status code in a JSON result.

Comment: The successful request will return the successful result if you want to return error then you should set the error code to the unsuccessful request.